# CSS Transition When Moved

Tags: html, css, transition

When the first element gets deleted, I want to make the other elements to slide into their new places instead of going instantly there. Using the code below, all of the other boxes move instantly to their new positions when you delete the first one. Eventually, there will be many rows of boxes.

```js
var pile = document.getElementById("pile");
function removeFirst(){
  pile.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
#pile{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="pile">
  <div class="box" onclick="removeFirst()">I'm the first box</div>
  <div class="box">I'm the second box</div>
  <div class="box">I'm the third box</div>
  <div class="box">I'm the fourth box</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var pile = document.getElementById("pile");
function removeFirst(thisDom){
    thisDom.style.transition = 'margin-left .3s'
    thisDom.style.opacity = 0
    thisDom.style.marginLeft = -thisDom.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px'
    setTimeout(()=> {
        pile.removeChild(thisDom);
    }, 300)      
}
```

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
#pile{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="pile">
  <div class="box" onclick="removeFirst(this)">I'm the first box</div>
  <div class="box" onclick="removeFirst(this)">I'm the second box</div>
  <div class="box" onclick="removeFirst(this)">I'm the third box</div>
  <div class="box" onclick="removeFirst(this)">I'm the fourth box</div>
</div>
```

Remove `dom` when the transition is complete

```js
var rectArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('rect'));

var box = document.getElementById('box')
var delay = 300
box.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target === box) return
    let index = e.target.getAttribute('data-index')

    var moveArr = rectArr.splice(index, rectArr.length)

    moveArr.forEach(item => {
        item.preLeft = item.offsetLeft
        item.preTop = item.offsetTop
    })

    box.removeChild(e.target)

    moveArr.forEach(item => {
        item.style.transform = `translate(${item.preLeft - item.offsetLeft}px,${item.preTop - item.offsetTop}px)`
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
        moveArr.forEach(item => {
            item.style.transition = `transform ${delay}ms ease`
            item.style.transform = `translate(0, 0)`
        })
    }, 1)

    setTimeout(() => {
      moveArr.forEach(item => {
        item.style.transition = ``
        item.style.transform = ''
      })  
    }, delay + 1)

    rectArr = [...rectArr, ...moveArr]
})
```

```css
.box {
    width: 336px;
    height: 336px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px pink;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.rect {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px orange inset;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="box" id="box">
    <li class="rect" data-index="01">01</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="02">02</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="03">03</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="04">04</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="05">05</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="06">06</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="07">07</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="08">08</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="09">09</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="10">10</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="11">11</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="12">12</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="13">13</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="14">14</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="15">15</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="16">16</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="17">17</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="18">18</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="19">19</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="20">20</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="21">21</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="22">22</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="23">23</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="24">24</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="25">25</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="26">26</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="27">27</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="28">28</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="29">29</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="30">30</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="31">31</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="32">32</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="33">33</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="34">34</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="35">35</li>
    <li class="rect" data-index="36">36</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there any way for the fourth box to move smoothly to its new position as well, instead of it moving instantly to the next line?

Comment: @Kira There is no easy way, If you want to meet your requirements, you must consider moving each DOM location.

Comment: @Kira I updated an example of dynamic transition, You can refer to the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS.

Try this one

```
#pile{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 144px;
    transition: padding-left 1s;
}
.box{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
.box:first-child{
    margin-left: -144px;
}
```

You can change margin according to your requirements.